# CSV from Windows Server Unable to open on Linux/Mac

Tags: windows, file, formatting, compatibility, csv

A small CSV file that was generated on a Windows server is **not** opening correctly on Linux/Mac.

The only way to open this file is via MS Excel for Mac, which gives the following prompt:

[image]

The CSV file has the proper extension `.csv` and "get info" in Finder shows that it is in-fact a CSV file. Weird thing is that it is called "Comma Separated Spreadsheet" rather than "Comma Separated Values":

[image]

When opening the file with TextEdit, the result is an empty file:

[image]

When using the `file` command in Terminal, the output is not "CSV" as it should be. It says it is `"Zip archive data"`:

[image]

Is this a common error with CSVs between OS's? Unable to find any resources online. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can use `cat` or `xxd` on the file in the terminal to see the raw file contents, rather than relying on TextEdit, which appears to be reading it as an RTF file. If it is an intact CSV file, you should see human-readable file contents. If the file is very large, use a command like `cat file.csv | head -n5` to just see the first few lines.

Comment: @JivanPal running `cat` on file does not display human-readable file contents. Suspect there is an error with how it is being saved on Windows server side. Thanks. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that the file was actually saved in MS Excel as a CSV file, and someone did not simply change the file extension from `.xlsx` to `.csv`? If the file extension was changed, this explains why `file` reports that it is a ZIP file, since XLSX files are simply zipped directories containing XML files. Try changing the file extension to `.xlsx` and see what happens.

Comment: @JivanPal that was exactly it, thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `file` reports that the supposed `.csv` file is a Zip archive, it may actually be an XLSX (Microsot Excel) file whose file extension was simply changed from `.xlsx` to `.csv`. Try changing the file extension to `.xlsx` to see if this is the case.